# Redirect page jQuery ajax if php returns true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i quite new to ajax and i am bit confused...

I have php function that returns a boolean(as 1,0) each time is called.

What i need is to somehow request that value and process it,
if it's 0 to do nothing and if it's 1 to show an alert message and redirect to index and destroy session.

Should i encode the value into json in the php file or not?

js:

```
$.post("activity.php", function(data,success) {
    if (data == '0') {
        alert("You are logged out");
        window.location = 'index.php';
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$activity = $userdao->activity($_SESSION['sessionid']);
if ($activity == 0) {
    $logout->userLogout($userid);
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: From your JS code, you don't need to. Just make sure PHP outputs 1 when success

Comment: i am bit confused with the way you request or send data through ajax, In order to output the data i will just echo $activity? because it doesn't work that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to process the response from the server using json. Then you need to encode the result on sever side. and you also need to change the response header content_type to application/json

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $data = array();
    $data['result'] = true;
    echo json_encode($data);
```

and on your client side

```
$.post("activity.php", function(data,success) {
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

and check your result from debug console in your browser.

Comment: thanks i managed to get it working until the point i need to do my check, if (data == 'true') { //do something } doesn't seems to run. It runs outside the if though. If i alert(data) i see "object Object" o.O

Comment: i used JSON.stringify(data) to achieve this that's for guiding me into the right path :D